# Hide USB Audio device on MAC OS X using custom kext

Tags: macos, usb, core-audio, iokit, kernel-extension

I am developing an application which does custom audio processing and sends the processed audio to the USB headset. My requirement is that the USB headset should not be visible to the user in the list of Audio output devices in System Preferences. Using "SampleUSBAudioOverrideDriver" code-less kext sample code from Apple, I'm able to change the interface name but I really need to hide it.
Is subclassing AppleUSBAudioDevice an option?

Comment: You can stop the USB audio driver from attaching to the device altogether using a codeless kext, and write your own userspace or kernel space USB driver. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @pmjordan I don't want to prevent the USB Audio driver from attaching to the device. All I want is the device to be hidden from the list of Audio output devices in System Preferences. I am hoping this should be possible using the codeless kext mechanism so that I do not have to write my own USB audio driver.

Comment: Are you the person behind Boom 3D?

Comment: @AlejandroCavazos Nope - I'm not the person behind Boom 3D.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to do pre-processing of a USB audio device's input and output streams in kernel space is to use the [AppleUSBAudioPlugin](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SampleUSBAudioPlugin/) API. This kext does not appear in the list of devices because it isn't an instance of IOAudioEngine, so there is no "hiding" involved.